# Add click event to trigger timestamp tooltips

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, timestamps

[image: 1]

I just *cannot* seem to get these to pop up on the stock Android browser or the latest Chrome for Android, in both desktop and mobile mode. Can a click event be added for these (and other tooltips/title text/alt text that are useful on the site)?

Comment: +1 same problem on iPad.

Comment: Wouldn't that conflict with the click action on some timestamps that are also links? e.g. _edited X mins ago_. Or do you mean just for the _answered X secs/mins/hours ago_ timestamps?

Comment: @Ren: While "asked yesterday" or "asked Apr 2 at 1:21" is not a link, the time portion of "edited ..." is (opens the revisions page). One option to ensure both behave the same way would be to make the **edited** and **asked** text into clickable links that display timestamp tooltips which auto-close after a while, as we have now for various other actions. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to approach the underlying problem, which is either with the stackexchange code or with the browsers. And if it is the browsers, perhaps the stackexchange code be altered to work around their limitations.

Comment: I just noticed this post is over a year old. Is this even still an issue for people using the aforementioned browsers?

Comment: As an aside: Firefox on Android shows the `title` attribute when long-pressing an `<a href=... title=...>` (like when [long-pressing the "edited" link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kPu6U.png)), while Chrome then shows the `href` value in its popup. (I do like the `title` to be shown when long-pressing XKCD images, but I like to see the URL when doing the same for links, so I don't particularly like Firefox doing that.) Long-pressing any non-link `<span title=...>` just opens the clipboard controls in both browsers. (@faint, not that I care, but nothing has changed as for the Android browsers.)