# Should we see timestamp when an answer was appeared on?

Tags: discussion, timestamps, time

Now (at least at Academia) an answer timestamp is in `answered N day(s) ago` format.

If there are two similar (correct) replies for a question, and a topic starter wants to mark the oldest as correct one she/he can sort the answers by the `oldest` button.

But should we users see and you StackExchange web developers implement a new timestamp format, for example `answered on HH:SS MMM DD, YYYY`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the exact time of posting as a tooltip, by hovering over the timestamp:

> [image]

Agree it's not very trivial, but having a friendly timestamp is nice and once you know about tooltips, you won't forget it. :)

Comment: :) how I know :)

Comment: How does that work on mobile, which doesn't have "hover"?

Comment: @MattGutting excellent question and I fear it's not possible at the moment. There is [already a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174854/add-click-event-to-trigger-timestamp-tooltips) asking to add such ability.