# Viewing 'Hotness' on mobile

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

On the [Hot Network Questions page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), apparently you have to hover over the question to see its hotness score.

Being on mobile, hovering over the question is impossible, so is there somewhere else, more mobile friendly which allows you to see the hotness points?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174854/add-click-event-to-trigger-timestamp-tooltips.

Comment: Anyway, agree it can be added to the text itself, not just as tooltip.

Comment: @sha I have no idea what the hotness score means, how is it calculated or what to make of it, and I don't care about it ever or almost ever. Please don't make it that visible.  Perhaps make it toggleable?

Comment: @Jan well, I know what it is and care a lot since it's vital part of the whole hot questions concept. IMO it's not less important than answers count and date asked, which are displayed.